# Search recordset for any word inside a string

Tags: ms-access, vba

I am attempting to search a recordset for any records that match a specific word inside of a given string using the instr() function. I can't seem to move inside the recordset correctly, usually getting a result only if it is the first or last value in the recordset field. Pardon the silly example. Below, if you type "I like tacos" into boxSentence, boxPlace should return "Taco Bell". That's essentially what i'm trying to accomplish.

```
Private Sub btnRecommend_Click()
dim db as database
set db = currentdb
dim rst as dao.recordset
set rst = db.openrecordset("Foods")

dim strsentence as string
me.boxsentence.setfocus
strsentence = me.boxsentence.text

rst.movefirst
do until rst.EOF
    if Instr(strsentence, rst("Food").value) then
        me.boxplace.value = dlookup("Place", "Foods", "ID =" & rst("ID").value)
    else
        me.boxplace.value = "Attempt Failed"
End If
rst.movenext
loop
rst.close
```

Comment: It seems that it will be more productive to form right SQL statement on which recordset'll base on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is that even if your code succeeds in finding a record in your recordset which validates the test expression for your `If` statement, you are still iterating over the remainder of the recordset and hence the value held by your boxplace control will be overwritten by the next record which does not validate your test expression.

One possible way to avoid this is would be to include an variable in the test expression for your `Do` loop to exit the loop when a match is found, for example:

```
Dim flg As Boolean
Do Until rst.EOF Or flg
    flg = InStr(strsentence, rst("Food").Value) > 0
    rst.MoveNext
Loop
If flg Then
    Me.boxplace.Value = DLookup("Place", "Foods", "ID =" & rst("ID").Value)
Else
    Me.boxplace.Value = "Attempt Failed"
End If
```